# How to install SDL library in Visual C++ 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation, sdl

Hey, How to install SDL library in VISUAL C++ 2008? I I am looking for a tutorial how to install, but I found nothing good :(( please help me?, sorry for bad english. Thanks :))

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [this tutorial](http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/msvsnet0508e/index.php) , as well as [Beginning Game Programming](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/index.php) for more info on general SDL usage.

Answer (score 1):

Add sdl\include to VC's include directories

Add sdl\lib to VC's lib directories

Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Detect 64-bit Portability Issues

Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library -> Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)

Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> SDLmain.lib SDL.lib

Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem Windows : (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)